# Is it possible to beat Brock in the first battle with him?

Tags: pokemon-ash-grey

In Pokemon: Ash Grey, the first time you face Brock you're *supposed* to lose to his Onix, as part of the storyline - you then follow Flint to the Hydro-Electric plant, power up Pikachu, and return to face him again.

But is it possible to beat him the first time? I've tried using Butterfree, Pidgeotto & Ratatta, all level 10 (for Sleep Powder, Sand Attack and Tail Whip respectively), but haven't been able to get off a shot with any Pokemon before being hit by a One-hit KO Rock Throw.

Have Onix's stats been boosted to make sure this battle is a wash? Or is it technically stil possible to beat him at this stage?

Comment: Scripted battles usually hit you with a quick knock out or once you hit a certain amount of damage to the boss (even if it is a killing blow!) or a timer expires the "you lose" sequence kicks in and it proceeds to kill you no matter what.

Comment: @CyberSkull - Normally yes, but this is a fan-made mod of Fire Red, and I somehow doubt they were able to change that much of the battle mechanics (as this sort of no-win scenario has never come up in a Pokemon game to date).

Comment: I thought it was just one I never heard of.

Comment: @CyberSkull - Fair enough. Well it's quite fun, the idea is that it follows the events that occur in the anime series/movies. (Hence this question, as Brock beats Ash the first time they battle in the anime)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes**, it is possible to beat him the first time you battle him. The battle ends, and the story continues as if you had lost (As per the story in the anime) which means you still need to beat him again.

I took him with:

- Butterfree: Lv 11
- Pikachu: Lv 12
- Pidgeotto: Lv 10
- Pidgey: Lv 10 (Didn't use)
- Ratatta: Lv 10
- Sandshrew: Lv 10 (Didn't use)

I managed to get a lucky Sleep Powder the first move - Onix missed his Rock Throw. I switched to Pidgeotto and Sand attacked him (maxed out accuracy loss). I then switched to Pikachu and Paralysed him with Thunderwave (He was awake by that stage), and started using Thundershock.

I got him to about half health when Onix got in a lucky crit Rock throw, and I switched to Ratatta and started with Tail Whip. Once his Defence was lowered enough I Quick Attacked him until he fainted.

Comment: Thunderwave dosen´t work against ground types.

Comment: @user54578 - in Pokemon Ash Grey, they changed Onix and Geodude to be pure-Rock type (instead of Rock/Ground), thus Electric can hit them both (like in the Anime)

Answer (score 3):

I caught a Psyduck in the lake to the right of victory road. It was lvl 21 and knew confusion, so it two hit KO'd onyx! Then he just acted like he beat me, and I was super confused.

Answer (score -1):

Well the answer is yes. First capture a Mankey nearby Pallet Town and like other Pokemon Games, train your party until their stats have become ok to that gym. Second Your Mnakey must have the low kick movement that's great against rock types. Thunderwaves and other accuracy ratio attacks are good too. Matter of fact a win or a lose in this case don't change the storyline, you got to play against him again but if you win you won't be blanked out and lose money!

Comment: I spent ages in the grass area near pallet, viridian and in the forest and I didn't run into one Mankey. Which area exactly did you catch it in?

Comment: It's in the area of 2 rows of grass right before you jump into the water and run into Misty. It is EXTREMELY rare to run into one, though, and they are severely weak (Level 2-3 at most)