# What is the best approach to beating LT. Surge in Pokémon Ash Gray?

Tags: pokemon-ash-grey

I recently found a rom hack online of FireRed called Pokemon: Ash Gray.

The game is essentially a playable version of the first couple of seasons of the Pokemon anime and has been quite a bit of fun so far. There have been some learning curves, especially with the gyms, but so far, I have been able to sweep past both Brock and Misty with relative ease on each playthrough.

However, every time I get to Lt. Surge, he sweeps my team of 6 level 20-25 Pokemon (I have tried Pidgeotto, Pikachu, Butterfree, Bulbasaur, Bellsprout, Oddish, Rattatta, Mankey, & Spearow) with very little effort. Only Quick Attack can do some damage, but he seems to have moves for every Pokemon type.

What do I do?

Comment: Rom hacks are perfectly on-topic.

Comment: I've seen online guides that have events after the fight, I think that they just made Surge and his Raichu crazy powerful to coincide with the show

Comment: It's probably a similar situation to the [fight with Brock](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/123128). Ash lost his initial battle vs Raichu - chances are the story will continue after the loss and you'll have to do something or talk to people before the battle is 'easier'.

Comment: After you lose, Nurse Joy gives you a Thunderstone that you can use to evolve Pikachu to Raichu. She claims this will help, but I still lose horribly.

Answer (score 3):

**Status Effects and a lot of luck.**

I've watched several videos now of this particular fight.  Most involve a status effect and stalling your goddamn heart out.  One used poison (after savescumming to get a fight where Raichu's first attack missed Bulbasaur), one used Leech Seed (similarly), and two used paralysis (a level 30 Pikachu might apparently take down Raichu in two Thundershocks and a Quick Attack).  Most of these take some degree of luck to still wear the big mouse down, though.  Arceus be with you!

"That's all I can do, is hope.  Hope that you can do something."  --[MunchingOrange](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s0r03xnQPWs&list=PL_VGbflD64WTfLVfMP-o5WYm1zPgqmBpZ&index=9)

Answer (score 0):

If there is something I know is that Raichu's weakness is its physical defense. This is why Quick Attack does some damage.

So try attacking its weak point with physical attacks. Physical attacks are (among others): Normal, Ground, Flying, Fighting, Poison attacks, etc.

If you get a Pokémon that can learn a Fighting attack like Mankey or Nidoran or a Ground attack like Sandshrew, they are the most useful options against LT Surge's Raichu.

Also, keep in mind that Electric-type Pokémon are weak against Ground-type attacks. The first Ground-type attack you can get in the game is Dig, which comes in a TM that you get after Cerulean City going south and right before the Hidden Village. Sandshrew, Nidoran and Mankey are ideal candidates to learn Dig.

I know this post is old but I felt that I needed to add my 50 cents. There might be many people like me reading it in the future.

Comment: Raichu is Electric type, but also (apparently) has fighting type attacks. So we really need to avoid Normal, Water, Ice, Flying, Rock, Dark, and Steel type Pokemon. The best defenses would be Grass, Electric, Poison, Psychic, Bug, or Fairy. So the best types for defense appear to be Pikachu, Caterpie, Weedle, Zubat, Clefairy, Paras, Bellsprout, Oddish, Bulbasaur.

Comment: Since Raichu is electric type, the best types for offense are... just Ground. So ideally one would want Pikachu or Clefairy using Dig? Otherwise... Pikachu, Beedril, Zubat, Paras, Bellsprout spamming physical attacks, yeah :(

Comment: Clefairy has low attack, so the ideal candidate is Pikachu using Dig.

Answer (score -2):

You could grind all of your Pokemon to a way higher level than Lt. Surge's Pokemon and easily beat it which would take a bit. Or, you can bring 1 Pokemon for each of his Pokemon that counters Lt. Surge's Pokemon so you have a severe type advantage and move advantage against all of his Pokemon. Also you can level your best Pokemon against electric and sweep his Pokemon.

Comment: So basically, just grind.

Comment: I tried that, but so far since posting this, he has taken down a Level 34 Pidgeotto, a Level 25 Raticate, a Level 26 Raichu, and a Level 18 Charmeleon (all on one go). One of the biggest issues is he has both Electric and Fighting moves, so if you send someone with a type advantage over Electric, he hits with either Mega Punch or Mega Kick.

Comment: ah... GRIND MORE BOIIII, thats a main part of pokemon, the grinding.

Comment: I get that, but are there any specific Pokemon that I should grind that would be most effective?

Comment: yes, grind a Pokemon that has moves that are effective against electric type Pokemon but is somewhat resistant to both fighting and electric moves

Comment: Try and find a Pokemon that has a super effective move against Raichu and resists all of Raichu's moves. Hard counters in pokemon are key. Then, grind it up so you just barely beat it or just 1 shot it.

Comment: I get that, but do you have any SPECIFIC Pokemon or moves that would help? So far, the only Pokemon I can find are: Pikachu (starter), Mankey, Sandshrew, Spearow, Pidgey, Rattata, Caterpie, Weedle, Zubat, Clefairy, Paras, Magikarp, Bellsprout, Oddish, Bulbasaur, Squirtle, Charmander, Meowth. Surge so far easily obliterates several of them with one or 2 shots.

Comment: Dont use any of the flying types or electric types, can you find any ground pokemon/moves?

Comment: find something that is not weak to electric and find a ground pokemon/move so that you can survive a few hits

Comment: or i guess you can max out a pokemon with quick attack with physical attack IV's

Comment: The only ground that I can find so far are Mankey, Rattata, Sandshrew, & Meowth. And each one of them gets obliterated by either Mega Punch, Mega Kick, & Slam. The only Pokemon so far that can do decent damage is Charmeleon with his fire attacks, but due to the game being based on the anime, once Charmander evolves into Charmeleon, he barely listens to you or any of your commands.

Comment: then get charizard

Comment: It doesn't matter if he evolves to Charizard, he still remains arrogant